# Two similar Jenkins projects gives different outcome

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, salesforce

I'm new to Jenkins and try to set it up to deploy to SalesForce. I've done first successful Project1 (script v1) which deploys fine and appear in SF org in "Deployment Status" page all fine, but this built is running without Unit Tests. So I've created a copy to deploy to same SF Org but modified unit test section as in script v2. Build was failing with Error "sharing operation already in progress" Then revert Script v2 to v1 but got same error, even after setting checkbox to Delete WorkSpace every time on finish. Is this some bug on Jenkins or I'm missing something else to tick?

UPD: I've started with one more Project linked to another SF Org (SF0), then after first created above two, so Project0 was linked with SF0, and those two Projects linked with SF1. But for some reason Project2 still deploy to SF0, I even tried to hardcode credentials, this does not help. (Proj1 deploys to SF1 as expected).

Both Projects read same Git branch.

Script v1

```
#!/bin/bash
#Exit from build:
#params: 1 - status, 2 - callback command to call before exit, 3 - comment text for  failed GitHub commit
exit_on_error() {
    if [ $1 -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo '=== ### exit_on_error ### ==='
        if [ "$2" != '' ]
        then
            $2
        fi

        echo 'failure' "$3"
        exit 1
    fi
}

echo '=================================================================='
cp /fullpath/sfdx-project.json ./sfdx-project.json


echo '======================== Login to SF ============================='
#Login to SF
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --username "$SF_USERNAME" --jwtkeyfile /fullpath/server.key --clientid "$SF_CONSUMER_KEY" --setdefaultusername --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com
exit_on_error $? '' 'SF auth process failed'

echo '======================== Deploy to SF ============================'
#Push sources to Scratch org and assign permission set to user
sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath ./force-app/main/default/
exit_on_error $? '' 'Source pushing process failed'

echo '======================== Run Tests on SF ========================='
#Run Apex tests
TEST_RESULTS_FOLDER="tests/${BUILD_NUMBER}"
mkdir -p "$TEST_RESULTS_FOLDER"
UNIT_TESTS_RUN_ID=$(sfdx force:apex:test:run --testlevel RunLocalTests --outputdir "$TEST_RESULTS_FOLDER" --json  | jq .result.testRunId -r)
if [ "$UNIT_TESTS_RUN_ID" = '' ] ; then UNIT_TESTS_RUN_STATUS=1 ; else UNIT_TESTS_RUN_STATUS=0; fi
#Exit if error occurs while running tests (ex. ORG has not test classes)
exit_on_error ${UNIT_TESTS_RUN_STATUS} '' 'Unit tests run process failed'

echo '======================== Run Test Report ========================='
#Run Apex Unit tests report
sfdx force:apex:test:report --testrunid $UNIT_TESTS_RUN_ID --outputdir "$TEST_RESULTS_FOLDER" --wait 10
UNIT_TESTS_FINAL_STATUS=$(cat "$TEST_RESULTS_FOLDER/test-result-$UNIT_TESTS_RUN_ID.json" | jq .summary.outcome -r)


echo '======================== Finish =================================='
#Mark build as failed if Apex Tests failed
if [ "$UNIT_TESTS_FINAL_STATUS" == 'Failed' ]
then
    echo "The build #${BUILD_NUMBER} has failed due to Apex Tests!"
    exit 1
else
    echo "The build #${BUILD_NUMBER} has successfully DONE!"
fi
```

Script v2

```
#!/bin/bash
#Exit from build:
#params: 1 - status, 2 - callback command to call before exit, 3 - comment text for  failed GitHub commit
exit_on_error() {
    if [ $1 -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo '=== ### exit_on_error ### ==='
        if [ "$2" != '' ]
        then
            $2
        fi

        echo 'failure' "$3"
        exit 1
    fi
}

echo '=================================================================='
cp /fullpath/sfdx-project.json ./sfdx-project.json


echo '======================== Login to SF ============================='
#Login to SF
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --username "$SF_USERNAME" --jwtkeyfile /fullpath/server.key --clientid "$SF_CONSUMER_KEY" --setdefaultusername --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com
exit_on_error $? '' 'SF auth process failed'

echo '======================== Deploy With Tests to SF ================='
#Push sources to Scratch org and assign permission set to user # -l RunAllTestsInOrg | RunLocalTests ;  -c (for Quick Deploy after)
sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath ./force-app/main/default/
exit_on_error $? '' 'Source deploy process failed'

echo '======================== Deploy Report ============================'
sfdx force:source:deploy:report --json
echo 'RESULTS END'
sfdx force:source:deploy:report --json | jq .result.testRunId -r)
if [ "$UNIT_TESTS_RUN_ID" = '' ] ; then UNIT_TESTS_RUN_STATUS=1 ; else UNIT_TESTS_RUN_STATUS=0; fi
#Exit if error occurs while running tests (ex. ORG has not test classes)
exit_on_error ${UNIT_TESTS_RUN_STATUS} '' 'Unit tests run process failed'


echo '======================== Finish =================================='
#Mark build as failed if Apex Tests failed
if [ "$UNIT_TESTS_FINAL_STATUS" == 'Failed' ]
then
    echo "The build #${BUILD_NUMBER} has failed due to Apex Tests!"
    exit 1
else
    echo "The build #${BUILD_NUMBER} has successfully DONE!"
fi
```

Comment: Was it against same org? If you didn't wait for the 1st deployment to finish (or some other administrator was messing around in Setup -> Sharing Settings for example) it might be a legit error. SF locks down the org during deployment & other serious setup activities. Ideally you'd see it on the page where you monitor deployments...

Comment: I'm using two SF sandboxes, I'm only developer. What I've noticed, for some strange reason second Project is not connected to same SF org but is linked with other, I have a few more Projects apart from those two, my config is taking correct Credentials, and even if I alter script to not use credentials, but simply hardcode them I still linked with other org... I've re-tested from proper bash console on that server, all works as expected it links to correct Org.. maybe Jenkins caching or something? .. last step: "Post-build Actions" -> "Delete workspace when build is done" seems not helping.

Answer (score 0):

I found what causing problem, for some reason my Project2 was authorized with two SF sandboxes, I've modified script to logout from SF, all works fine now. Just a few words about script, it deploys into Sandbox instead of using DevHub org as SF recommends. Link to latest script: https://gist.github.com/Radamanf/802e1e352d711222dbdf8dd9be532202